# Django: Template logic not rendering query data, no errors given either

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a template based view that doesn't seem to be working(or atleast doesnt seem to be working on the page that needs to render it).

Here is the View:

```
class LocationManager(View):

template_name = "dash/LocationManager.html"


def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        locations = user.get_profile().owned_locations
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'locations': locations})
    except:
        return render(request, self.template_name)
```

Here are the models that have to do with this view:

```
#in Location models
class Location(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    street_address = models.TextField(blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)

#in UserProfile models
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    api_key = models.TextField()
    pp_api_key = models.TextField(blank=True)
    owned_beacons = models.ManyToManyField(
        Beacon,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='owned_beacons'
        )
    owned_locations = models.ManyToManyField(
        Location,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='owned_locations'
        )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.user.username
```

And finally the template:

```
        {% for location in locations.all %}<tr>

            <td>{{location.name}}</td>
            <td>{{location.street_address}}</td>
            <td>{{location.zip_code}}</td>
            <td>{{location.region}}


        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

Yet the template does not render anything in relation to the form logic(the rest of the template loads fine). No errors are raised either which is why this is making it hard for me to understand why the template logic/view isn't working properly. Any ideas would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try {% for location in locations %}

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I got rid of the .all at the end, and it seemed to work better, yet my main issue was with Try/Except. Fixing both of those ultimately got it to work. So thank you!